# how to use svg as image src in iis 6

Tags: html, image, svg, iis-6

I am running IIS 6, I know it is out dated but that is what I am stuck with.  I am wanting to use svg files for image src.  I added the .svg mime type of image/svg+xml and I can request svg files through the browser and it displays correct instead getting 404 errors.  I don't care about supporting IE 8 or older so I don't need a fallback image.

The problem now is that if I put this in my html I get an empty image but I put this url in the browser the svg image show fine.

This works

```
http://localhost/test.svg
```

This does not work

```
<img src="test.svg" />
```

So how do I get the svg image to show as an image in my html?

Answer (score 0):

This issue ended up being that the SVG file that was generated did not have the width and height specified.